# How do i change the navbar color?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

Just trying to learn asp.net core mvc and want to know how i give the navbar from the default _Layout a custom background color.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the color of  class `navbar` in layout.And you'd better to add `!important` or the css may be corverd by the other css.Example:

```
<style>
        .navbar {
            background-color: green !important;
        }
</style>
```

Or you can create a new class and add the class to the navbar you want:

```
<nav class="customClass navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
<style>
            .customClass {
                background-color: green !important;
            }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `navbar` is part of bootstrap style.

You have few options here.

1. The hard one is to  [customize the bootstrap theme](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/overview/) .
2. The easy dirty and fast is to overwrite the `navbar` if only this is what you wish to change.
3. And one in the middle is to use a page to [Generate your own Bootstrap navbar](https://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/) download it and apply it